# Only show error on one form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a custom password form field. Now when i have 2 password fields and the password doesnt meet requirements. Both fields report the error.

Is there a way I can remove this error in case it has already occurred on the first field?

```
class PasswordField(forms.CharField):
    def validate(self, value):
        super(PasswordField, self).validate(value)
        if not value or re.match("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d!.@#$%^&*()?<>]{8,}$", value):
            return value
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The password does not match the requirements. "
                                  "It should be at least 8 characters long, contain 1 Uppercase letter, "
                                  "1 lowercase letter and 1 number."))

class PasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password = PasswordField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password", required=True)
    password_2 = PasswordField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Confirm Password", required=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either move your logic into the `PasswordForm`'s `clean_password` method, or write it as a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/) and then apply this validator to the first password field.

```
def validate_password(value):
    if not value or re.match("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d!.@#$%^&*()?<>]{8,}$", value):
        return value
    raise forms.ValidationError(_("The password does not match the requirements. "
                              "It should be at least 8 characters long, contain 1 Uppercase letter, "
                              "1 lowercase letter and 1 number."))

password = PasswordField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password", required=True, validators=[validate_password])
```

Note, note you may want to use django's [`validate_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password) and then move possibly move your logic into your own custom validator.

Otherwise, to keep the logic in the field, just make your `password_2` a [`CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#charfield) that uses the [`PasswordInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput) widget so that you only use one of your custom fields in the form.

Comment: Thanks for the solid info. I didnt think of changing 2nd password to CharField.